# How can I make this a horizontal list?

Tags: css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Right now my users are displaying vertically. I would like them to display horizontally side by side. I know this is a very simple to do however, I am having a hard time getting it to be how I would like. Thank you in advance.

**User/Index**

```
<div class="page-header">
<center><strong><h1> All Users </h1></strong></center>
</div>

  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <div class="user horizontal-align col-md-2">
     <%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)), user %>
      <br><%= link_to user.name, user %></br>
        <% if current_user.admin %>
     <%= link_to "Delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>

        <% end %>
    <% end %>
 </div>

<div class="center">
<%= will_paginate @users, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>
```

**User CSS**

```
.user {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I think `col-med-8` should be `col-md-8`

Comment: can you show us the rendered HTML? this is clearly a css issue so the ruby is irrelevant and limits the number of people that could help you

Comment: @PeterVR Thank you for the md fix. I added my CSS within the question however, I wasn't really using it. I'm a complete beginner so thanks for your help.

Comment: How many across do you want? You could add `col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12` to your `div.user` this will show 2 users side by side for large and medium screens and vertically on small and extra small screens. For 3 users use `col-??-4` remember grids are 12 wide so you want 12 / x amount of users.

Comment: @engineersmnky I would ideally like to have 5 across. When I try this all it does is stagger everything to the right. They are still vertical unfortunately.

Comment: Also bootstrap offer helper classes for text positioning. use `text-center` class instead of `<center></center>` tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Isolate .user from the .col-x-x containers. The col containers should be used for layout only. Styling the .user element is overriding the BS3 layout styles.
2. Remove any width definitions in your CSS for .user. Allow width to fall.
3. Wrap nested columns with .row

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zktfu52t/2/

EX:

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-4">
    <div class="row">
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <div class="horizontal-align col-md-2">
            <div class="user">
                <%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)), user %>
                <br><%= link_to user.name, user %></br>
                <% if current_user.admin %>
                <%= link_to "Delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much. I can't vote up so I checked the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-4">

  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div class="user col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center">
      <%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:thumb)), user %>
      <p><%= link_to user.name, user %></p>
      <% if current_user.admin %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

With this css

```
.user{
     margin:0.2%;
     display:block;
}
```

This will give you 5 across on medium and large screens and vertical stacks on small and extra small screens. A Quick [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zktfu52t/) for you.

Also you have unclosed div tags here:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading center">
```

Comment: The jsFiddle shows them as vertical. I would like for them to be horizontal. Thanks for that! The code moves everything to the right and the users pics are still vertical. Thanks again for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: @Annette stretch the box and you will see that once it gets to a certain size they go to 5 accross. If you always want 5 across regardless of screen size you need to add `col-sm-2 col-xs-2` I have updated the fiddle to show you

Comment: @Annette as for the moving to the right that is what you specified when you add an `offset-x` it will shift `x` grid-cells to the right. you can remove offset to have everything inside a left aligned 8 grid cells.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try and let you know. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score -1):

First things first: stop using the center tag. It's deprecated and unreliable. Use CSS for your styling needs.

To get your users displayed horizontally, you need to wrap all of the user details (links, in this case) in some sort of element. A div is probably best. Then you need to set those elements to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Thanks, I will get rid of the center tags. I included my user css however, I wasn't really using it which I know I should be obviously.

Comment: @Annette, the included CSS has a selector for a `user` class. I can't see anywhere in your HTML where there is something that actually has a user class. Wrap all three of the user links inside of the loop with a `<div class="user">`

Comment: I was adding it within my dev site, I wasn't fast enough. Unfortunately it is still showing up vertically. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks again for all your help.